# Get sum of the same class

Tags: jquery

I have

```
<div id="english">
   <ul>
        <li>English</li>
        <li>Instructor Name</li>
        <li class="grade">85</li>
   </ul>
</div>

<div id="math">
    <ul>
        <li>Math</li>
        <li>Instructor Name</li>
        <li class="grade">80</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="science">
    <ul>
        <li>Science</li>
        <li>Instructor Name</li>
        <li class="grade">90</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<p id="grade-sum">Sum of grade here</p>
```

My question is how I am going to get the sum of that class grade using jquery.
The sum should be 255.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $('li.grade').each(function(){
        sum += parseInt(this.innerHTML, 10)
    })

    $('#grade-sum').text(sum);
})
```

Comment: @MattCharlton That's the `radix`, if you don't specify it, you will get unexpected results.

Comment: @undefined do you know how to pass the #grade-sum value to a php value?
Example
<p id="grade-sum"><?php echo $grade-sum; ?></p>

Comment: @arjay0601 If you want to pass the data to the server you should use AJAX.

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery, you can easily iterate and get the sum.

```
​$(document).ready(function(){
    total_grade = 0;
    $('.grade').each(function(){
        total_grade += parseInt($(this).text());
    })

   $('#grade-sum').text(total_grade);
});​
```

check this fiddle

Comment: Do you know how to pass the #grade-sum to a php variable?
like <p id="grade-sum"><?php echo $grade_sum ?></p>

Answer (score -1):

```
var sum = 0;
$("li.grade").each(function(index, element){
  sum += parseInt($(element).text());
});
console.log(sum);
alert(sum);

$('#grade-sum').text(sum)
```